# Create an MS access form to perform FTP to a server

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

`I have a database in Ms Access:`

<kbd>**Server**</kbd> <kbd>**Name**</kbd>
   -----------------------
   <kbd>A1</kbd>       <kbd>Jack Frost</kbd>
   <kbd>B2</kbd>       <kbd>Harry Potter</kbd>
   <kbd>A2</kbd>       <kbd>Peter Parker</kbd>

I would like to:

**=>**  Export the data from a table to multiple text files, in the same folder as the database file, using a query(depending on the filter) in **VBA**.

`I tried working out with this query, but this query saves the outputfile only in 'my documents' folder.`

```
SELECT NAME INTO [TEXT; HDR=YES;DATABASE='E:\Learning Access.A1.txt']
FROM NAMES
WHERE SERVER="A1";
```

**=>** Upload those files to the respective servers using FTP(depending on the name of the file - Server name will be same as file name) - in **VBA**.

**=>** Collect logs for each FTP session into text files using **VBA**.

I need VBA code to perform the steps mentioned.

--
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We won't write code for you. Please try it yourself and come to us if you have specific problems getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As for the FTP part, you may want to try using `Declare` to access the Windows API directly, it contains some functions from wininet.dll which can do some basic FTP upload/download.

Look specifically for the functions [InternetOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [InternetCloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [InternetConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FtpOpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [InternetWriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).